# Is it possible to check in non-microsoft files for example files with .txt or .pdf format?

Tags: development

I am trying to enable checking in function for files with .txt or .pdf format. Is there a way to do this as i know that it's possible to check out the files in sharepoint. But im not sure how to check in for it?

For docx. format , it's easy as it is a built in with microsoft sharepoint. So, how do i achieve for non-microsoft files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You enable check in/check out on the document library level, not the individual file level, though Microsoft Office has an awareness of it and prompts you via the action bar.

Go to Library Settings -> Versioning Settings then set 'Require documetns to be checked out' to "Yes".

Comment: hi james.. i have enable the setting to require documents to be checked out.. but now i just do not know how to display a messagebox to enable check in everytime the user edit something

Comment: You can't - your users will need to use the SharePoint interface to explicitly check out a file before editing, and check in when they're finished.